# Does a Java Thread have its own process ID?

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I want to get the process ID of a Thread to see how much memory it takes.

Comment: Okay, thank you (: You may want to post this as answer so i can accept it ;)

Comment: I am sure, yes. (; My idea was to check the RAM Usage of a single thread via the process ID.

Comment: In that case, you need to run what the thread does in a separate process. Generally, this is more trouble than it is worth.  Instead it can be easier to run your application with a profiler and associate the biggest structures with a thread using your judgement.

Comment: Why not use Processes instead of Threads?

Comment: Thread IDs don't let you find out how much memory is used by a specific thread. The question is practically meaningless given that objects can have multiple references from multiple threads. Voting to close.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends a lot on the OS and how it manages threads. Theoretically it also depends on how the JVM implements threads, but all modern JVMs implement them as native threads.

On Linux each thread <strike>will</strike> used to get its own process ID, but most tools hide all but one thread per process (i.e. you don't usually see them unless you explicitly ask for them, `ps` uses the `-m` flag for example). This is caused by the fact that the Linux kernel doesn't really make much of a difference between threads and tasks.

*Edit:* as I just learned this is no longer *necessarily* the case: you **can** create a thread with the exact same PID as the parent, in which case the threads will be distinguished by different thread IDs.

**However** since a thread shares its memory with all other threads in the same process, this **doesn't** help you find out "how much memory a thread takes", since all threads in a process will use the exact same amount (and they all use the same, so the real used memory is `shown_memory_use` and not `shown_memory_user * number_of_threads`).

Comment: If 'a thread shares its memory with all other threads in the same process' how can it have a distinct process ID? Thread ID, yes.

Comment: That's just the way Linux works. A separate process ID does not imply that the memory is separated, even a regular process shares memory with the parent directly after forking it (copy-on-write though). You can create threads that share the same PID (clone(2) with CLONE_THREAD), but the older way of doing it was to give each thread a PID of its own. Not sure what kind of clone today's JVMs use though.

Comment: @Tim Jansen So a Linux process ID is really a thread ID. That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @EJP: it kind-of does: getting the (process|thread) ID from a thread is highly dependent on the OS **and** getting the "memory used per thread" is not a useful metric, because it includes all memory occupied by the *process*.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer As posed the question has no answer, because no threadID can tell you how much memory the thread is using. Voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

Threads do not have PIDs, processes do. As such what you're asking is not possible. There is also no reliable way to retrieve your PID from within a Java process (although the first part of the value returned by `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()` usually is the PID).

Answer (score 3):

As the name implies, PID means process ID. Each process can spawn multiple threads, which all share the same PID. Are you sure you don't mean Thread ID?

Answer (score 2):

A feature of thread is that is shares the heap with all other threads.  This means that any one thread can potentially use almost all the memory of the process.  The only thing which a thread doesn't have access to is the stack or local variables of another thread.

As such it is not useful to try to determine how much memory an individual thread uses.  Instead it can be useful to determine how much memory a data structure uses. (Although this can have similar difficulties)

It is worth noting that main memory is relatively cheap. Your situation may be different but a typical new server with 24 GB can cost as little as £1K. You can buy a 96 GB PC for around £2K. Sometimes it is not worth worrying about how much memory you are using until you know it is a problem.