# Could a Java PID in a kernel oops belong to a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, linux-kernel

If I am getting the following Kernel oops

`kernel: CPU:    1`
`kernel: EIP:    0060:[<f956cb90>]    Tainted: G     X VLI`
`kernel: EFLAGS: 00010202   (2.6.13-15-smp)`
`kernel: EIP is at usb_lock_device+0x10/0x20 [usbcore]`
`kernel: eax: f9588dc4   ebx: 20303330   ecx: 00000023   edx: 20303330`
`kernel: esi: ffffffed   edi: 080b6b70   ebp: f95769a0   esp: e7969f2c`
`kernel: ds: 007b   es: 007b   ss: 0068`
`kernel: Process java (pid: 11135, threadinfo=e7968000 task=f53c2020)`
`kernel: Stack: f95769de 0000001a 00000000 0000002b 00000000 00000023 080b6b70 f774ab40`
`kernel:        00000000 00000001 0000002b 0000002b 00000000 0000001a 00000000 00000001`
`kernel:        ecd3c60c 00000001 e942d7c0 00000023 080b6b70 f95769a0 c0170fbc e7969fa4`
`kernel: Call Trace:`
`kernel:  [<f95769de>] usbdev_read+0x3e/0x290 [usbcore]`
`kernel:  [<f95769a0>] usbdev_read+0x0/0x290 [usbcore]`
`kernel:  [<c0170fbc>] vfs_read+0xac/0x190`
`kernel:  [<c0171391>] sys_read+0x41/0x70`
`kernel:  [<c01042ab>] sysenter_past_esp+0x54/0x79`
`kernel: Code: c0 14 e9 f4 d6 d1 c6 8d 74 26 00 c3 eb 0d 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 89 c2 b8 c4 8d 58 f9 f0 ff 00 0f 88 b6 04 00 00 <f0> ff 4a 24 0f 88 ba 04 00 00 c3 90 8d 74 26 00 53 b9 c4 8d 58`

Could the Java PID listed in the oops be that of a thread ? Or does this have to be a Java process?

PS: JDK 1.6 used on Kernel 2.6.13-15-smp

Comment: On linux, it could be.  Each thread can have a different PID.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090479/does-a-java-thread-have-its-own-process-id

Comment: @sorencito I did read that before posting, but it actually confused me more =) Thanks.

Comment: Ok. In your case, I am pretty convinced its a process. Its the normal case and your kernel output says it's a "Java process". Anyway, just guessing...

Comment: If it happens repeatedly you can try to have the program print it's pid early in operation, and compare that to what is printed in the later oops.  Of course, userspace (java, your program, whatever) is not at fault for a kernel oops - at most, it's just what exposes a kernel (likely in this case driver) bug.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out that this is indeed a thread ID. I used top -H and observed the Java instance along with threads running and was able to see the PID causing this; it is the thread responsible of polling a USB device.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yes - what the kernel calls a PID, userspace calls a TID.